# Python, RegEx, re.split() with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I have to split a loooong filename with several delimiters (e.g. "AA_BB1234_CC123456789_2020-01-31_001.xml) into bits in order to create a new name from it, using the date-part and the current filenumber at the end. By pure chance I found out that

```
data = re.split(r'[_-.], filename)
```

throws a "bad character range" error, but if I change the order to hyphen, underscore, dot, it works just fine:

```
data = re.split(r'[-_.]', filename)
```

Why is that?

Comment: That's because hyphen needs to be scaped, you can use it for `a-zA-Z0-9`, so you need to add a backslash to escape it  `a-zA-Z0-9\-`

Answer (score -1):

The hyphen is a special character when it appears within a character set, but only when it's between two other characters. In this situation, it defines a range for the set. When it's placed as the rightmost or leftmost character, it's treated as a literal hyphen.

`[a-dz]`: Matches `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, or `z`

`[-adz]`: Matches `-`, `a`, `d`, or `z`

`[adz-]`: Matches `-`, `a`, `d`, or `z`

There's an exception to this when using a negated character set, as the `^` itself is also a special character:

`[^-adz]`: Matches a character other than `-`, `a`, `d`, or `z` (not a range between `^` and `a`)